# Method for pre-processing JSON for EXTJS TreeGrid?

Tags: json, extjs, preprocessor

I'm trying to determine the best method for pre-processing JSON for usage in an EXTJS TreeGrid. It's my understanding that EXTJS is expecting JSON to be formatted in the following manner:

```
{
    "text":".",
    "children": [
        {
            Location:'New Jersey',
            iconCls:'task-folder',
            expanded: true,
            children:[
                {
                    Building:'North-west Building',
                    iconCls:'task-folder',
                    children: [
                        {
                            Computer: '#12345',
                            Owner: 'Tommy Maintz',
                            iconCls: 'task',
                            leaf: true
                        }, 
                        {
                            Computer: '#98776',
                            Owner: 'Robert Maintz',
                            iconCls: 'task',
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, the data source I am working with outputs flat JSON as such:

```
{
    Computer: '#12345',
    Owner: 'Tommy Maintz',
    Building:'North-west Building',
    Location:'New Jersey'
}
 {
    Computer: '#98776',
    Owner: 'Robert Maintz',
    Building:'North-west Building',
    Location:'New Jersey'
}
```

What EXT methods are at my disposal to pre-process my JSON to work with a TreeGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function/method that would do what you want, hence a coding is inevitable. Some advices:

1. You wouldn't work with the string but you would use `var o = Ext.decode(json);` to convert the raw json to object `o`
2. You can use `Ext.each()` to iterate through the resulting array or object
3. I'd write a recursive routine that would construct the resulting nested object
4. When you have the object with the desired structure you can use tree.setRootNode(result) to populate the tree.